# How to split components of url in php

Tags: php, html

I want to split each components of a url and echo it separately. Like http://www.example.com/username  Now i want to split each part of url and echo it as http, 
Www,
Example,
Com,
Username.

Comment: 1. You should specify the code that you've tried

Comment: 2. Your criteria is inconsistent: what about `http://example.com/user-name?hello=there` ?

Comment: I am not able to find how to start for it and right @diego help me with this type of url also.

Comment: you should define what "each components" mean to you. you can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get scheme, host, port, path, querystring, etc. but a querystring has different fields, host may have multiple subdomain, etc. So, what's are "components" to you?

Comment: How to echo or replace each component that i got by parse_url () ?

Comment: @RajivSharma Use `explode(',', $domain)` to split the domain at `.` characters. Use `explide('/', $path)` to split the pathname at `/` characters, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Does the example here help? [http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php](http://parse_url)

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';

var_dump(parse_url($url));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
?>
```

Edit after the comments:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/username';

$scheme=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
$path=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$path2 = explode("/", $path);
$host=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

echo "$scheme",", ";

$pieces = explode(".", $host);
echo "$pieces[0]",", ";
echo "$pieces[1]",", ";
echo "$pieces[2]",", ";
echo "$path2[1]","\n";
?>
```

Should yield:

```
http, www, example, com, username
```

Comment: How to echo each components separately.

Comment: He wants to split `www.example.com` into `www`, `example`, `com`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using **parse_url()** function.

```
mixed parse_url ( string $url [, int $component = -1 ] )
```

You will find the documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php

Hope that helps for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you could find a regular expression which would filter on . / ? = and :// I think you would be able to solve your problem with this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php